# Were male shrine prostitutes homosexuals?

Tags: history, 1-kings

1 Kings 14:24 (NIV)

> *There were even male shrine prostitutes in the land; the people engaged in all the detestable practices of the nations the LORD had driven out before the Israelites.*

Did these prostitutes serve male or female clients?

Comment: Both - all comers as did the female shrine prostitutes

Comment: Given the patriarchal character of the then society, probably only male pilgrims of this pious vice enjoyed their service in the shrine; and a same-sex sexual practice was not regarded by non-Jews a "per se" perversion (unless by great minds such as Socrates who was against it /cf. his behaviour with Alcibiades who unsuccessfully tried to have sex with  him/). One needs to go deeper into ethnography of this epoch and consult variety of sources - written, painted, carved on stone etc.

Comment: I have added quote formatting and the version of the Bible you have quoted. Please remember to this yourself in future.

Comment: Given sodomy can be practiced by both hetero- and homosexuals the act itself is what is detestable. Sodomy being defined as oral and/or anal.  Prostitution likewise was detestable to God. I can understand your question asks specifically about homosexual relations but it does not make the act less abominable if it was practiced by heterosexuals. 1 Kings 14:24, 15:12, 22:46, 23:7. The Hebrew in the verse you quote qadesh speaks of sodomite, male sodomite, hence it was homosexual prostitution but it doesn’t rule out heterosexual sodomy with the male prostitutes. So Dottard is right, both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hebrew word qāḏeš is from the root q-d-š meaning “holy, sacred”. For this reason it is widely assumed that it is used in the same sense as the Greek ἱερόδουλος “temple prostitute”, literally “sacred slave”. The word occurs in the Hebrew Bible both in the masculine and the feminine form. It is very difficult to imagine that free-born women could have had the opportunity to engage the services of prostitutes of either sex; both the male qāḏeš and the female qāḏešā would have been there for male clients only.

Having said this, the word “homosexual” is not appropriate in the context of the ancient world. The ancients did not classify people according to their “sexual orientation”. They spoke rather about sexual practices, positively or negatively as the case may be.

Answer (score 0):

The Hebrew does not contain "shrine" or "prostitute":

[image]

The word קָדֵ֖שׁ *qā·ḏêš* is only used in one other verse, Deuteronomy 23:17:

[image]

In both cases, it's masculine singular for "perverted". English translations derive rather freely from the Hebrew meaning. The LXX renders this as:

> καὶ σύνδεσμος ἐγενήθη ἐν τῇ γῇ, καὶ ἐποίησαν ἀπὸ πάντων τῶν
> **βδελυγμάτων** τῶν ἐθνῶν ὧν ἐξῆρεν Κύριος ἀπὸ προσώπου υἱῶν Ἰσραήλ.

*βδελυγμάτων* means "abominable, loathsome".

There's one use of the word in masculine plural in 1 Kings 15:12 with the same pattern of derivation in the translations:

[image]

Young's literal translation is closest to the original meaning:

> and also a **whoremonger** hath been in the land; they have done according
> to all the abominations of the nations that Jehovah dispossessed from
> the presence of the sons of Israel.

A whoremonger is a person who has dealings with prostitutes, not himself a prostitute.

Comment: In Deuteronomy 23:17 qāḏeš is rendered by σύνδεσμος, not by βδελυγμάτων.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. [σύνδεσμος](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%83%CF%8D%CE%BD%CE%B4%CE%B5%CF%83%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%82) means "bond" or "joint".

Comment: I have The interlinear Bible by Green which gives a line of Greek with the English below and the Strong's number above. But the Interlinear Bible Hebrew English by Jay Green does not give the Strong's numbers above the Hebrew line. Please tell me where you found the interlinear that does all three lines. It would make my research so much easier.

Comment: https://biblehub.com/interlinear/1_kings/14-24.htm

Comment: No, קדש is a male prostitute just like קדשה is a female prostitute. When Judah thinks he sees a prostitute he calls her a קדשה, which is the female version of קדש.

Comment: No, he calls her לְזוֹנָ֑ה (lə·zō·w·nāh), which is a different word. https://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/38-15.htm